# How to test through io.mockk a method that was called several times with different parameters?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, kotlin, mockk

PS: Code will be in Koltin

For example, I have my service class that does something and injects some other service.

```
class MyService(
   private val someOtherService: OtherService
) {
   fun doSomething() {
       someOtherService.someMethod("foo")
       someOtherService.someMethod("bar")
       someOtherService.someMethod("baz")
   }
}
```

Here is my test to my MyService class which mocks OtherService:

```
internal class MyServiceTest {
    @MockkBean(relaxed = true)
    private lateinit var someOtherService: OtherService

    @Test
    fun `my test description`() {
        every { someOtherService.someMethod(any()) } just Runs

        verify(exactly = 1) {
            someOtherService.someMethod(
                    match {
                        it shouldBe "bar"
                        true
                    }
            )
        }
    }
```

As a result, `"bar"` parameter will be expected but will be `"foo"` parameter instead and the test will fail.

Reason: `someOtherService.someMethod("foo")` will have called before `someOtherService.someMethod("bar")`.

However, I want to verify that every method called exactly once. How I can do that?

Answer (score 15):

You could just:

```
verifySequence {
  someOtherService.someMethod("foo")
  someOtherService.someMethod("bar")
  someOtherService.someMethod("baz")
}
```

It verifies that only the specified sequence of calls were executed for mentioned mocks.

[Mockk verification-order](https://mockk.io/#verification-order)

If not, you could capture the parameter using a list and verify the values later.

[Mockk capturing](https://mockk.io/#capturing)

Comment: Can the OP verify that this is an acceptable answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Service method to test

```
someMethod(str: String) : String
```

When you need to verify multiple calls to the same method with different parameters

```
 val stringSlots = mutableListOf<String>()
 every { someService.someMethod(capture(stringSlots)) } answers { "string" }
```

Verification

```
stringSlots.size shouldBe <Number of calls expected>

val firstSlot = stringSlots[0]
val secondSlot = stringSlots[1]
val thirdSlot = stringSlots[1]
// Do any verifications after 

firstSlot shouldBe "foo"
secondSlot shouldBe "bar"
...
```